# Excel conditional formatting if value is between or equal to values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have been trying to use conditional formatting to create a Gantt chart. So far I have not been very successful. Here is a screenshot of part of the chart:

[image: http://imgur.com/dQAvXLW]

The current formatting is hand made.

I want the cell to turn pink if it meets the following condition:

The week number (in row 4 of current column) must be greater than or equal to the start week (in current row column D) AND smaller than or equal to the end week (in current row column E).

I have tried to add conditional formatting with a formula. The formula I came up with looks like this:

```
=IF(AND(ADDRESS(4,COLUMN(),2)>=ADDRESS(ROW(),4,1);(ADDRESS(4,COLUMN(),2)>=ADDRESS(ROW(),5,1)))
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is all sorts wrong, unfortunately!

- `ADDRESS` gives you the address of the cell, not its value... so you are comparing whether an address is bigger/smaller
- You have both checks as `>=` rather than one greater and one less than
- You have a mix of `,` and `;` (but I guess that is probably just editing onto this site!)

To enter the formula:

- go into cell `F6`
- Conditional formatting > new rule > use a formula...
- `=AND(F$4>=$D6,F$4<=$E6)`
- This format can then be copied and pasted into your gantt body

To explain:

- in Conditional formatting, Excel will modify the cell references of non-absolute referenced cells. The formula you enter is the one for the top-left of the range that the rule applies to
- We can fix the row or column with the `$`in the address

Comment: Thank you! I was clearly thinking this was harder than it actually was.. The function you gave me is working perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The way I always make Gantt chars in Excel is to put a formula in all the cells that results in a character in that cell and then use conditional formatting to format the cell. You can "hide" the characters by making them (in the conditional formatting) the same color as the background.

So, for example, if you have starting week numbers in column B and ending week numbers in column C and week numbers in row 1, then I put something like this in D2: `=IF(AND(D$1>=$B2;D$1<=$C2);"B";"U")`. (B = Bar, U = Unbar). Copy-paste down and right for as much is needed. Use conditional formatting to make "B" show pink background and pink letters and "U" to show white background and white letters.

Note: using this technique, you're able to use several different colors (for example to mark milestones or to show baseline and adjusted planning, as long as the data is in some column and you extend the formula to giver different letters). If you're just looking for a bar/no-bar, then you could make it simpler and just put in the `=AND(D$1>=$B2;D$1<=$C2)` formula. This results in a `TRUE` (bar) or a `FALSE` (no bar).